# Determine if a string is a palindrome without changing input

Tags: c++, pointers, palindrome

I am trying to write a program in C++ that will take a string as an input from standard cin input and determine if the input is a palindrome. I cannot change the string in any way and I cannot copy it.

The code must contain something like `bool isPalindrome( const char* x){}`

My attempt is listed below.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome( const char* x)
{
  string str = *x;
  int n = str.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    int j = 0;
    while (isalpha(str[i]))
    {
      if (isalpha(str[n-j-1])) 
      {
        if (tolower(str[i]) == tolower(str[n-j-1]))
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
      j +=  1;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  string str;
  cout << "Enter your string: ";
  getline (cin, str);
  const char * x ;
  x = &str;
  if (isPalindrome(x) == true)
  {
    cout << "Yes it is!" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "No, it's not." << endl;
  }
  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am not the best c++ programmer and the use of pointers is still a little confusing to me. Does the argument `const char * x` mean that inputs are initialized as pointers who's values are constant? Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I forgot to mention... the input may contain punctuation but still can be a palindrome. For example " Madam, I'm adam! " is a palindrome. But I cant remove the punctuation from the string since the string is not allowed to be changed.

Comment: This task doesn't require pointers at all.

Comment: @user3261977: One obvious way would be using iterators.

Comment: Why cannot you copy the string? Anyway, just skip punctuation and spaces by incrementing the iterator

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
bool isPalindrome(const string& s)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = s.size()-1;
    while(a<b)
    {
        if(s[a] != s[b]) return false;
        ++a;
        --b;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** About you second question:
`const char * x` is a pointer to an array which elements are `const`,
`char * x` is a pointer to an array,
`char * const x` is a `const` pointer to an array,
`const char * const x` is a `const` pointer to an array which elements are `const`

**EDIT2:**
It looks like you almost had it in your code, but you return `true` too fast, [after you find a single character match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507300/1123898). But don't use `char *` when you already use C++ `string`. You can make the code more clear if you just use the `string` object.

Here's how I'd do skipping non alpha characters efficient way:

```
bool isPalindrome(const string& s)
{
    int a = -1; // points before the first character
    int b = s.size(); // points after the last character
    for(;;)
    {
        // in each iteration shift `a` and `b` at least by one
        do ++a; while(a<b && !isalpha(s[a]));
        do --b; while(a<b && !isalpha(s[b]));

        if(a >= b) return true;
        if(toupper(s[a]) != toupper(s[b])) return false;
    }
}
```

Or not as efficient but probably harder to make a bug (oh, but it copies the string and you didn't want that):

```
#include <algorithm>

bool badchar(char c)
{
    return !isalpha(c);
}

bool isPalindrome2(const string& s)
{
    string copy(s);
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), copy.begin(), ::toupper);
    copy.erase(remove_if(copy.begin(), copy.end(), badchar), copy.end());
    string rev = copy;
    reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
    return copy == rev;
}
```

I prefer the first way.

Comment: I forgot to mention... the input may contain punctuation but still can be a palindrome. For example " Madam, I'm adam! " is a palindrome. But I cant remove the punctuation from the string since the string is not allowed to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Logic is simple. Divide the string from the middle. Compare first to last and so on till middle. If characters are not equal at any point, then its not palindrome.

Code snippet (untested):

```
char string[] = "level";
int length;

length = strlen(string);

for(int i = 0, j = length - 1; i < (length / 2) ; i++, j--) {
    if(string[i] != string[j]) {
        // Not palindrome
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning away right after the first character, so the remaining aren't compare any time

```
if (tolower(str[i]) == tolower(str[n-j-1]))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Only return if there are any difference, otherwise wait until all the characters have been compared

Answer (score -1):

If you are using C++, then use **vector**. First insert the string into a vector, reverse the vector and then check the original vector and the reversed vector is equal or not. If equal then palindrome otherwise not.

You don't need any pointers. simple. :)